# strongloop: can not set breakpoint in certain model.js files

Tags: node.js, strongloop, node-inspector

I start the debugger with "slc debug" and Chrome starts up.  I want to set a breakpoint on line 100 of report.js

I can't do it.  Won't let me.

Any ideas why?

In other file such as events.js I can click on the linenumber and the blue breakpoint shows up.

Is the Strongloop node inspector any different from the standard one?

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too. Try this (sound weird), but its work for me :

1. type "slc debug"
2. the chrome will open up, with one new tab
3. explore to your "report.js" file, set break point at your line (Note : the break point will not show)
4. open up new tab at same chrome
5. type in the debug path (same like the one at step 2, or you can see it at your debugger). ex : http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858

At the new debug tab, the break point will show up.

Hope it help, just sharing what i been through.

thanks.